# How to store specific object in HashMap with iterating id as key

Tags: java, hashmap, software-design

I am working on on a program. I was storing Users in a ArrayList, so I had a UserCollection class which is acting as the storage class for the Users. But seeing as the UserCollection is thought of as a 'database' each user entry in the database should have a unique id. Initially I had a userID as a field in the User class but now I'm trying to handle the id part in the UserCollection. If I were to use a hashmap, where the key would be the id, the value being the User how would I go on about iterating the id so that every time a new User is stored into the hashmap, they key keeps iterrating from 1 to n amount of users.I'm also using CRUD methods to store/remove/update etc the Users.

```
public class UserCollection{

Map<Integer, User> userMap = new HashMap<Integer,User>();

public User create(User user){
 userMap.put(??,user) // not sure how to iterate the id or what to put in it
 return user;
}

public User read(Integer keyID){
  if(userMap.containsKey(keyID)){
     return userMap.get(keyID); //something definitely wrong
  }
}

//Other remaining CRUD methods after. 

}
```

Originally I just had an ArrayList which held Users. But Because I realized in a database Users will have unique id's now I'm confused how I would handle them. If i handle them in the HashMap do I still need to have a userID field in the User class ?

Answer (score 1):

You have asked a couple of questions here. I'll take each of them in turn:

1. How can I ensure that each user has a unique ID?

The simplest way to do this is to have a static field that keeps track of the largest generated id:

```
class User {
    private static int largestID = 0;
    private final int id = largestID++;

    public int getID() {
        return id;
    }
    ...
}
```

This works but has plenty of problems with it. As soon as you store users & restart the programme, or want to reuse ids, it needs changing.

Another approach is to just find the largest id for existing customers from your collection. The following sample code uses Java 8:

```
class UserCollection {
    private final Map<Integer,User> users = new HashMap<>();

    public int nextID() {
        return users.keySet().stream()
            .mapToInt(n -> n).max().orElse(-1) + 1;
    }
}
```

This is inefficient but probably good enough for a lot of applications.

2. Do I need to store the ID in the User class?

You have two options. Either you store it in the class and provide a mechanism for getting the ID (as above). Or you ensure that everything that deals with users stores and returns IDs, not references to objects. This allows the client of the method to then access the User using the ID.

Both of these are legitimate solutions. If you use the first (storing the ID in the class) then you should change your method for adding a User to your collection:

```
class UserCollection {
    public void addUser(User user) {
        users.put(user.getID(), user);
    }
}
```

If you use the second, the ID field must be final because clients are relying on it not changing.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following to ensure that your Users have a unique ID for the life of the class.

```
public class UserCollection
{
   private static int id = 0;
   private static final Object lock = new Object();

   private Map<Integer, User> userMap = new HashMap<Integer,User>();

   public User create (User user)
   {
     // only add one user at a time to the map
     synchronized (lock)
     {
        id++;
        userMap.put(id, user);
     }
     return user;
   }

   // Rest of the class
}
```